# VBS script to scan and install all devices

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to figure out a way to scan all devices (without drivers installed) and install them one by one automatically.

I've made a simple script that adds/removes a registry value for driver locations, since we have a server with all the current drivers and it's updated frequently, so instead of pointing device manager to that location manually the script does it for me.
Problem is we work in a production environment and we have a lot of different devices to install, and doing it manually takes too long, even with the script i have to click each device and update the driver, the scripts just makes it a little easier by pointing it to the server with the drivers.

So basically i'm try to make the script add the location (this works fine ATM) and them update each device without prompting the user.

```
Option Explicit

Set ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim s, ws, rl

rl = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\"

s = InputBox("Please select what you want to do" & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "1 - Clear all, set default driver path." & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "2 - Default path + production drivers" & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "3 - Default and production path + Skylake drivers")
If s = 1 then
        ws.RegWrite rl & "DevicePath", "%SystemRoot%\inf" , "REG_EXPAND_SZ"
    ElseIf s = 2 then
        ws.RegWrite rl & "DevicePath", "%SystemRoot%\inf; B:\LocalDrivers\; \\ccdsrv01\shares\Resources\Drivers\Client" , "REG_EXPAND_SZ"
    ElseIf s = 3 then
        ws.RegWrite rl & "DevicePath", "%SystemRoot%\inf; B:\LocalDrivers\; \\ccdsrv01\shares\Resources\Drivers\Client; \\ccdsrv01\shares\Resources\PreProd\SkyBay (Skylake-SunrisePoint)\New" , "REG_EXPAND_SZ"
End If
```

Comment: `pnputil.exe` and `devcon.exe` could help...